# How to make an element remain active when click on other element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, weebly

I'm working with this code:

```js
$('.tab1-c').show();
$('.one').click(function(){
   "use strict";
    $('.tab1-c').show();
    $('.tab2-c').hide();
  $('.tab3-c').hide();
  $('.tab4-c').hide();
});

$('.two').click(function(){
 "use strict";
    $('.tab1-c').hide();
    $('.tab2-c').show();
  $('.tab3-c').hide();
  $('.tab4-c').hide();
});

$('.three').click(function(){
 "use strict";
    $('.tab1-c').hide();
    $('.tab2-c').hide();
  $('.tab3-c').show();
  $('.tab4-c').hide();
});

$('.four').click(function(){
 "use strict";
    $('.tab1-c').hide();
    $('.tab2-c').hide();
  $('.tab3-c').hide();
  $('.tab4-c').show();
});
```

```css
.tab-nav-wrapper {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  font-family: Open sans; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}


.tab-content-wrapper {
  background-color:#fff;
  width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: 15px 35px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align:justify;
}


.tab1-c , .tab2-c, .tab3-c, .tab4-c{ display:none

}

.tab-nav-wrapper ul li {
  text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem ;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}



.fonts-content {
  font-family: droid serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #000000 !important;
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.two {
 
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  background: #d48344;
}

.three {
  
}
.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 49%;
  background: #706a87;
}

.four {
 
}
.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 74%;
  background: #47435f;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #d4bba7;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Glegoo; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-color: #000 !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one">Story #1</li><!--
 --><li class="two">Story #2</li><!--
 --><li class="three">Story #3</li><!--
 --><li class="four">Story #4</li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like for the element below each category to remain active when I hover over the other categories. I don't want it to jump back to its original position when clicking a different category. I want it to remain depending on which category I click.

Help please?

Comment: Only necessary to use `use strict` once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using a little extra CSS  and jQuery (I added `#oneActive`, `#twoActive`... ).  Additionally, I cleaned up your jQuery a bit and rewrote most of it to get active to work.

```js
$('.tab1-c').show();

mapping = {
  "one":"tab1-c",
  "two":"tab2-c",
  "three":"tab3-c",
  "four":"tab4-c"
};
$('.one, .two, .three, .four').click(function(){
   $('.' + mapping[$(this).attr("class")])
    .show()
      .siblings()
      .hide();
    $(this)
      .attr('id', $(this).attr("class") + "Active")
        .siblings()
        .attr("id","");
});
```

```css
.tab-nav-wrapper {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  font-family: Open sans; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}


.tab-content-wrapper {
  background-color:#fff;
  width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: 15px 35px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align:justify;
}


.tab1-c , .tab2-c, .tab3-c, .tab4-c{ display:none

}

.tab-nav-wrapper ul li {
  text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem ;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}



.fonts-content {
  font-family: droid serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #000000 !important;
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.two {
 
}

.two:hover ~ hr, #twoActive ~ hr {
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  background: #d48344;
}

.three {
  
}
.three:hover ~ hr, #threeActive ~ hr {
  margin-left: 49%;
  background: #706a87;
}

.four {
 
}
.four:hover ~ hr, #fourActive ~ hr {
  margin-left: 74%;
  background: #47435f;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #d4bba7;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Glegoo; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-color: #000 !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one">Story #1</li><!--
 --><li class="two">Story #2</li><!--
 --><li class="three">Story #3</li><!--
 --><li class="four">Story #4</li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab1-c">test1</div>
  <div class="tab2-c">test2</div>
  <div class="tab3-c">test3</div>
  <div class="tab4-c">test4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have one more question, I'm trying to plug this code into Weebly.com, but they other codes going on so the code it's not exactly working. The hover section works but not the active. It still hovers back to the beginning. Do I have to specify for an exact variable?? I'm not that familiar with jQuery, so your help will truly be appreciated!

Comment: You can revert part of it back to the old code.  If you don't want to use the variable name mapping, just change it.  More likely than not, weebly has some styling stuff conflicting with it, and there is really nothing I can do to fix that (even given the website).  If you wish, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: It started working a few minutes ago, I guess I just had to wait a little for it to update the Jquery. Thanks again you are a hero!